# TV comedy about spaceship, done in the style of "Metropia"

Tags: story-identification, tv

There was a TV series sometime between 2001 - 2010, I think on the Sci Fi channel, about a spaceship crew that were trying to get back home.  It was very funny but got canned after 1 or 2 seasons.

It was in the style of the movie "Metropia" where there are cutout heads on animated bodies. One episode was about them throwing a party and people got so wasted they had sex without remembering and woke up all confused.

I remember the captain was an idiot who took nothing seriously and didn't really care about what the crew did. This show was HILARIOUS but I can't remember what the name was or if it was on Sci Fi or Comedy Central.

Answer (score 3):

Think I found it... Is it [Outer Space Astronauts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_Space_Astronauts)?

> Outer Space Astronauts is a comedy television series which aired on Syfy, created by Russell Barrett.
>
> The main characters have live-action "real" heads connected to computer-generated and animated bodies in a completely digital environment.
>
> The crew travel through space on a ship named the O.S.S. Oklahoma.

Comment: If so, this would be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/88038/need-help-remembering-the-name-of-a-sci-fi-comedy-series-from-around-2007/104306#104306 if this gets accepted.