# Need help remembering the name of a sci-fi comedy series from around 2007

Tags: story-identification

The show featured the heads of live action actors pasted onto ridiculously small CGI bodies.  There was a bight red moronic alien character, the captain was a drunk, the badass tactical specialist was played by a woman with a fake mustache.  Thought it was brilliant and want to watch it again.

Comment: This sounds amazing.

Comment: American made? Any recognisable actors?

Comment: Yeah, it was American and was on SyFy or Comedy Central if I remember right.  I've looked up the programming schedules for both networks from 2005 to 2010 and none of the titles listed stood out in my memory of the show, so it may have been another network.  None of the actors were anyone I recognized.  The show really felt as though it were inspired by, or was poking fun at the BBC series 'Hyperdrive'.

Comment: OUTER SPACE ASTRONAUTS!!!!!  I found it!!!

Comment: @WilliamRussell:
You can post it as an answer. You won't be able to accept it for a few days, but it helps later people looking for the same information.

Answer (score 5):

As per William's comment above, this would be *[Outer Space Astronauts](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1265869/)*.

> In the future, many courageous souls journey to the far reaches of the galaxy, seeking knowledge, adventure, and the thrill of exploration. They are integral to the survival of the human race and truly have 'the right stuff.' The rest are the Outer Space Astronauts. The slovenly Captain Ripley commands the "space-ially" challenged crew of the O.S.S. Oklahoma as they go about their daily routine of... working in space.